# How to delete dom element from jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i want to delete a particular class from my object as my requirement is to delete that dom data before displaying content. I have written a sample code but not able to get why that is not working. I jquery's remove is also not working. Please help me to get it solve. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // complete html
    var test;
    test = $('#issue_detail_first_row').html();

    var x = $(test).find('#issue_detail_nav').not('.p1');

    $('#sett').html(x);
 });

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="issueDetailContainer">
        <div  id="issue_detail_first_row">
            <div>
                <div id="issue_detail_nav">
                    <div>test</div>
                    <div id="gett">
                        <div class="p1">
                            this content need to be deleted 1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="p1">
                        this content need to be deleted 2
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="sett">
</div>
```

Comment: How are you using $.remove()?

Answer (score 15):

You need to remove the content from the DOM directly.

```
$("#issue_detail_first_row .p1").remove();
```

That will select the `.p1` elements and remove them from the DOM

Answer (score 9):

you can use remove function on javascript object.

If you want to preprocess it before displaying.

example

```
var a =$("#issue_detail_first_row").html();
var jhtml =$(a)[0];   
$(jhtml).find('.p1').remove();
alert($(jhtml).html());
```

now use jhtml . 
demo

http://jsfiddle.net/WXPab/14/

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you're trying to *duplicate* a section, but without the `.p1` elements.

You could use the [`clone()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to clone the section, the [`remove()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to remove what you don't want, and then insert its HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var test = $('#issue_detail_first_row').clone();  // clone it

    test.find('.p1').remove();  // find and remove the class p1 elements

    $('#sett').html( test.html() );  // insert the new content
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YDZ9U/1/

Only thing is that you'll need to go through and update the IDs in the clone, so that they're not duplicated on the page.